# Unrecognized font-family material? in React-Native Vector Icons IOS only issue

Tags: ios, react-native, google-material-icons, react-native-vector-icons

Material Icons not working in ios, using react-native-vector-icons. All other type of Icons arw working. They are configured the same way. Followed all steps mentioned in react-native-vector-icons documentation. ALso the answers from other stack-over flow answers. I see that normally people get error like "Unrecognized font-family material-icons?" but in my build it's just "material".

I'm using ,
"react-native": "~0.63.4"
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",

```
import MaterialIcons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
    <MaterialIcons
         resizeMode={"contain"}
         size={20}
         name={"favorite-border"}
         color={"#3C093C"}
         >
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDJ6s.png)

I have followed everything mentioned in react-native-vector-icons documentation, also tried the fixes like removing fonts from copy pods resources, The fonts are already been added to info.plist. It's just in the case of materilicons this happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that you add it to Resources if you do it with auto-linking check this Build Phase `Copy Pods Resources`:

[image]

Comment: Firstly , thanks for the reply. yes, its added but the issue still exists, If I remove any other font family from fonts folder, this same error shows up. So I think it's something particular to material Icons. All other are working properly. do you have any other insight?

Comment: @belonkelorb try to clean the build folder from xcode, and question if you remove and add again for other fonts it works?